# How to get a mini-calendar as a block on sidebar?

Tags: views, datetime

I am using a [Event Calendar](https://drupal.org/project/event_calendar) module to display the Calendar and it is configured using [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) and linked with the events and popup the event when clicked.

I want a mini-calendar on front page with same events but like a mini calendar.

I have tried creating block for the view but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Pretty Calendar](https://drupal.org/project/pretty_calendar) module.